# After jmeter ramp up period, does it keep that same rate after all thread groups are loaded?

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, load

After jmeter ramp up period, does it keep that same ramp up rate to load thread groups?

Answer (score 0):

Once all all threads are launched in specified Ramp-Up time, those threads may stay alive or get killed based on the loop count you specified.

Once a thread is launched, then it is based on the loop count, the lifetime of the thread based upon.

Scenarios:

**1 thread, 1 loop**:
1 thread will be created and run for one iteration and terminates.

**1 thread, 10 loop**:
1 thread will be created and run for ten iterations and terminates.

**10 threads, 1 loop**:
10 threads will be created and run for one iteration each and terminates.

**10 threads, 10 loop**:
10 threads will be created and run for ten iterations each and terminates.

**10 threads, Forever loop**:
10 threads will be created and run for infinite iterations each and terminates when you click `Shutdown/Stop` button.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I mean when threads are loaded at a rate of  one user per 30seconds . Does JMeter keep on this rate after the first loop?

Comment: Yes. JMeter threads will be created on equal regular intervals based on ramp-up time. 1. suppose, 10 threads to be created in 10 seconds, then each thread will be created on each second. 2. suppose, 10 threads to be created in 5 seconds, then 2 threads will be created on each second. loop count does not have any affect on it.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, How to calculate the concurrent user is on the system after I load all the users sequentially? Say I loaded 200 users in 400 seconds, and the test case is login , do sth, then logout total 6 steps with 5 seconds of think time. The whole process takes about 30 seconds when run alone (one user). After loading up the users, the requests of each user seems mingled together, does not seem to be paced on the loading rate of the thread at start up.

Comment: Use https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/ Or Generate DashBoard report which contains the Active Users graph. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html